# Fetching result from mysql stored procedure in php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I had a long query, so I tried to make things simpler and made a procedure that gives me the same result, and the procedure has 3 `IN` arguments, and works fine when I call it from mysql console. The problem is when I call the procedure through php. Here's the shortened version of the code:

```
$ride = mysqli_query($dbCon, "call home_ride('$listFrom','$listTo','$date');")

$startStation = mysqli_query($dbCon, "blabla");

while( $rideData = $ride->fetch_assoc() ){ 
              $departureData = $startStation->fetch_assoc(); <--Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean
...
```

And this error appears not on the `$ride->fetch_assoc()` but on `$startStation->fetch_assoc()` which I just can't understand. Of course all of this worked fine before I tried to make this procedure.

And also it works when call to a procedure returns empty set.

Comment: I think your problem is with the query "blabla" that I don't think is valid SQL.

Comment: That's the problem, `blabla` works fine, but when I add procedure it somehow makes that `blabla` query not work..

Comment: The problem is that the procedure works, and you now reach the contents of the while loop where `false` (the return value from `mysqli_query` on a non working query) is actually used.

Comment: The while loop stops when that query is fetched for the first time, I just tested that. And the return table of procedure is exactly the same(called from mysql console) as before adding the procedure..

Comment: that's because you used `fetch_assoc()` twice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Where?

Comment: `while( $rideData = $ride->fetch_assoc() ){ 
              $departureData = $startStation->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: But those are different queries

Comment: it doesn't matter; you're using that function twice in the loop; you can't do that. Btw, I only commented back here because I stayed here. You'll need to ping me back if you want. However, I need to state that the accepted answer is rather of poor / low-quality by Stack's standards. Drop-in code with no explanation doesn't help anyone to know exacty why your code failed in the first place. @wdc

Comment: @wdc *"But those are different queries"* - Can you explain why you accepted that answer below which obviously doesn't have two separate queries, and Lord only knows where they pulled `model_get_menus_list()`. The solution to your posted code is simple; run the fetching function once in the loop and echo out which row(s) you wanted. It's pretty obvious here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- First when I tried this accepted answer it worked for one procedure so i accepted it, and then it didn't when I added second one. 
Actually I have three queries out of which I tried to make procedures to make the code better, but before I had three queries, and three fetch_assoc calls in that while loop and it worked fine.. But thanks, i'll try